# Fermat's Little Theorem: $24^{(54n + 1)} +11 \equiv 1 \mod 19$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm supposed to use Fermat's Little Theorem $($ If $p$ is a prime and $p$ doesn't divide $a$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv1 \mod p)$    and  to find the least residue of the following:

$24^{(54n + 1)} +11 \mod 19$, where $n  \in \mathbb{Z}^+.$

The 11 is trivial, so I'm just concerned with reducing the term with  $24^{(54n + 1)}$.

(24, 19) = 1, so the Theorem applies.  $24\equiv 5\mod19$, so

$24^{(54n + 1)} \equiv 24^{54n}(5)\mod19$

At this point, I'm not really sure what to do next because I can't really see how to bring the theorem into play!

Comment: Double-check the numbers since it is not correct as stated

Answer (score 0):

$24^{54n}=((24)^{54})^n$, since $54=3*18$, $24^{54}=1$ mod $19$ since $24^{18}=24^{19-1}$, so the answer is $16$ mod $19$

Answer (score 0):

Since $54n+1\equiv 1\pmod{18}$ you have
\begin{align}
24^{54n + 1} +11
&\equiv 24+11\\
&\equiv 35\\
&\equiv 16\pmod{19}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We have $24 = 5\mod 19$. Hence,
$$ 24^{54 n + 1} + 11 = 5^{54 n + 1} + 11\mod 19. $$
As you noted, the difficult part is in the first one of course. You need to apply Fermat's theorem which states that
$$ a^p = a^1\mod p$$
if the gcd of $a$ and $p$ is $1$. In our case, you are going to apply it where $a = 5$ and $p = 19$. The key part is that you note that Fermat's theorem implies that
$$ a^n = a^{n\mod (p-1)} \mod p$$
holds if $a$ and $p$ are relatively prime. Once you see this, it is easy to find the actual result since $54 n + 1 = 1\mod (19-1)$ and you are left with
$$ 5^{54 n + 1} + 11 = 5^{54 n + 1\mod 18} + 11 = 5^1 + 11 = 16\mod 19. $$